# Display lat/lon coordinates of drawn rectangle in Folium

Tags: mapping, geospatial, geojson, folium, ipywidgets

I am trying to create a widget with ipywidgets and folium that allows me to print to the screen the lat/lon coordinates of a rectangle drawn by a user. In the widget, the user will be presented with a map, draw a rectangle, and click "submit". Upon clicking "submit", the widget will display the northern/southern/western/eastern coordinates of the rectangle the user just drew.

I have the widget built except I cannot find where the coordinates of the drawn rectangle are stored.

```
``
import folium, folium.plugins
import ipywidgets as ipyw # must be below v7.7
from IPython.display import display, HTML, clear_output
%matplotlib inline

# Create map (with specified size) and center on USA, include draw tools for rectangle only
f = folium.Figure(width=750,height=350)
m = folium.Map(location=[39, -95],zoom_start=3).add_to(f)
draw = folium.plugins.Draw(draw_options={'polyline':False,'polygon':False,'rectangle':True,
                                         'circle':False,'marker':False,'circlemarker':False}).add_to(m)

# Add plugin for displaying lat/lon of mouse position
formatter = "function(num) {return L.Util.formatNum(num, 6) + ' º ';};"
folium.plugins.MousePosition(position='topright',separator=' | ',empty_string='NaN',
                             lng_first=False,num_digits=20,prefix='Coordinates:',
                             lat_formatter=formatter,lng_formatter=formatter
                             ).add_to(m)

# Display map on widget page
map_output = ipyw.Output(layout=ipyw.Layout(width='100%'))
with map_output: display(m)
    
# Create 'submit' button that will print lat/lon coordinates of drawn rectangle to the screen
button_submit = ipyw.Button(description='Submit',tooltip='Send',style={'description_width':'initial'})
button_output = ipyw.Output()
def on_button_clicked(event):
    with button_output:
        clear_output()
        ''' PRINT LAT/LON OF DRAWN RECTANGLE HERE'''

# Display widgets components: map on top, submit button below
button_submit.on_click(on_button_clicked)
page1 = ipyw.VBox([ipyw.HBox([map_output],layout=ipyw.Layout(justify_content='center')),
                   ipyw.HBox([ipyw.VBox([button_submit,button_output])],
                             layout=ipyw.Layout(justify_content='center'))
                   ],layout=ipyw.Layout(display='flex',flex_flow='column',
                                       align_content='space-around',align_items='center'))
display(page1)
``
```

Any advice for printing the lat/lon coordinates to the screen is appreciated!